# When shall I include an intercept in linear regression?

Tags: regression

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When is it ok to remove the intercept in lm()?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7948/when-is-it-ok-to-remove-the-intercept-in-lm)

When shall I include an intercept in linear regression?

Hi all,

In general, given some data, how shall I decide if I should include an intercept in linear regression?

Could you please give me some pointers?

Thank you!

Comment: In general, you should have a good reason _not_ to include the intercept, not the other way around. See the thread above, which has lots of useful info.

Comment: Luna, I appreciate the good questions you've been asking here & the productive discussions that have been brought about because of your efforts. As you are becoming more active here, it would be worthwhile to become more familiar with CV's style of asking questions. We tend to discourage repeating the title, & having conversational elements such as "Hi all" & "Thank you!". The idea is that these questions ultimately become a searchable public record & that stuff ends up getting in the way.